# Iterated function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let
$$f(x)=x−\frac{1}{x}$$
Find the number of real solutions to $f(f(f(f(x))))=1$. Do I evaluate it completely, or is there some other way. After third composition it got nasty, so I left it.

Comment: ***Point of Fact:***  $f(1) = f(-1) = 0$, but $f(0)$ is not defined, so not all reals values may be iterated upon:  $f(f(1))$ and $f(f(-1))$ ***ain't happening***.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe first that for any number $a\in {\mathbb R}$ the equation
$$ f(x)=a $$
has two real solutions:
$$ x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}(a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}). $$
First we solve the equation
$$ f(x)=1$$
and get two solutions $a_1, a_2$, then we solve two equations
$$ f(x)=a_i$$
and get four solutions $b_1, \ldots, b_4$. We have to do four steps, in the end we have $16$
real solutions of the equation
$$ f(f(f(f(x)))=1. $$

It is useful to see the graph of $f$: this function is a bijection from $(-\infty,0)$ to ${\mathbb R}$ and also from $(0,\infty)$ to ${\mathbb R}$. This shows that all above solutions are distinct and we really have $16$ different real numbers in the end.

EDIT. As Robert Lewis observed, one has to be careful with $f(\pm 1)=0$. However in our procedure this situation does not appear.